# Printing a hash

Tags: perl

**Purpose**
I am making a hash and printing it to count frequencies of words in a large document.
In the result files, I am getting some unexpected entries.

**Problem**
The hash has an extra output HASH(0x55b0ac)

**My progress with the troubleshooting**

After breaking up the code into smaller parts and testing each component individually, I figured out the problem is with printing a hash. I've written a smaller segment of the code here which replicates the same issue.

Code:

```
my %testhash = {};
$teststr = "using this for testing this that";

foreach $word (split(' ', lc $teststr)) {
$testhash{$word}++;
}

foreach $word (sort keys %testhash) {
    print $word."\t".$testhash{$word}."\n";
}
```

**Expected output**

```
for     1
testing 1
that    1
this    2
using   1
```

**Obtained output**

```
HASH(0x55b0ac)
for     1
testing 1
that    1
this    2
using   1
```

**Note**
I know my problem can be solved by using an if condition and not printing a line if $testhash{$word} is NULL. My question is to understand the reason for this unexpected entry. Is it something to do with declaring the hash or with printing it?

EDIT:
Every time I rerun the code, the number 0x55b0ac changes

Comment: You initialize your hash with a hash-ref (to an empty hash), so when you print the hash contents, you get a hash-ref as one of the values. You should either leave off the initializer or use an empty list: `my %testhash = ();`.  This is what Paulchenkiller said, so I'm not going to add an answer.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLeffler! I changed my code and it works fine :D

Comment: It's also a very good idea to use `strict` and `warnings`. `warnings` would have told you that `Reference found where even-sized list expected at ...` pointing to the line where you initialize your hash with a hash ref.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is the first line. This works:

```
my %testhash;
my $teststr = "using this for testing this that";

foreach my $word (split(' ', lc $teststr)) {
    $testhash{$word}++;
}

foreach my $word (sort keys %testhash) {
    print $word."\t".$testhash{$word}."\n";
}
```

Comment: You wrote, that your `0x55b..` Part changes, thats normal. the number is the actual address of the SV header for the referred to thingy.

Comment: Yup, I just read @jonathanLeffer's comment and googled up hash-ref. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
 use Data::Dumper;
 # your other code here
 print Dumper(\%testhash);
```

I usually do the above... Data::Dumper is a very useful module

Answer (score 0):

I think like this..

```
my %testhash;
my $teststr = "using this for testing this that";
$testhash{$_}++ for split /\s+/, lc $teststr;
print $_ . "\t" . $testhash{$_} . "\n", for sort keys %testhash;
```